# Statistics - Calculating $60$th percentile from data given for $25$th, $50$th , $75$th and $90$th

Tags: statistics

I am not a stats person. Help me.

If $25$th percentile is $3822$, $50$th is $4780$, $75$th is $5856$ and $90$th is $7106$, what is $60$th percentile?

Comment: Do you know if the data follows some kind of distribution?

Comment: Anything between $4780$ and $5856$, inclusively.

Comment: Specifically I am trying to see if 5431 is at or above the 60th percentile. Intuitively I can see that it is but I need to be sure.

Comment: Matti, I am probably not sophisticated enough to answer that question but the data is used to determine compensation for a large group of people.

Comment: This question is essentially asking: I have function values $f(25)=3822$, $f(50) = 4780$, $f(75) = 5856$ and $f(90)=7106$. What is  $f(60?)$. As you see, it would be of course possible to make some kind of guess, but ultimately it would be beneficial to have some more information about the function.

Comment: It seems like your best approach would be to average 25,50,75,90  (I guess $\frac{25+50+75+90}{4}=60$ for a reason)...

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out already, you can't be absolutely sure without knowing what the distribution is. Modelling with the Normal Distribution may not be accurate since the data do not appear to be symmetrical.

One method to estimate the 60th percentile could be to use linear interpolation, so you would have $$\frac{P_{60}-4780}{5856-4780}=\frac{60-50}{75-50}$$
which leads to $$P_{60}\simeq5210.4$$

It is possible that this is an underestimate since the cumulative frequency curve is likely to be concave over this interval.

Comment: Thank you David, your answer is extremely helpful!